foreach me duplica los registros de un arreglo php mysql
Tengo una funcion la cual carga un arreglo
<?php
    public function obtenerCategoriaParticipante($idparticipante)
    {
        
        $sql = "SELECT clasificacion.idPArticipante as idParticipante,
                       modalidades.nomModalidad as nomModalidad,
                       categorias.nomCategoria as nomCategoria 
                FROM clasificacion, modalidades, categorias 
                WHERE clasificacion.idModalidad = modalidades.idModalidad
                AND clasificacion.idCategoria = categorias.idCategoria
                AND clasificacion.idPArticipante = $idparticipante 
                ORDER BY idClasificacion";
        $resultado = $this->db->query($sql);
    
        while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $this->categorias[] = $row;
        }
            return $this->categorias;
    }
?>

y la llamo desde una ventana para desplegar los datos, el problema que tengo es que se me duplica los registros, lo que veo es que se van acumulando en el arreglo
<tbody>

<?php 
      $dats = new Participante();
      $dats->idTorneo = $_SESSION["idTorneo"];

      foreach($this->model->listarParticipante($dats) as $data): ?>
<tr>
  
  <td><?php echo $data["idParticipante"] ."---". $data["primerNombre"] ." ". $data["primerApellido"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $this->model->countCategoria($data["idParticipante"]); ?></td>

  <td>
    <table>
    <?php 

      foreach($this->model->obtenerCategoriaParticipante($data["idParticipante"]) as $datacat): ?>

      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $datacat["nomModalidad"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $datacat["nomCategoria"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td>Boton</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</tbody>


para cada uno me tiene que traer 4 registros, pero me los duplica.
Estos son los registros que deberia traerme


que es parte del query que esta en la función
SELECT clasificacion.idPArticipante as idParticipante, modalidades.nomModalidad as nomModalidad, categorias.nomCategoria as nomCategoria
FROM clasificacion, modalidades, categorias 
WHERE clasificacion.idModalidad = modalidades.idModalidad
AND clasificacion.idCategoria = categorias.idCategoria
AND clasificacion.idPArticipante = 11
ORDER BY idClasificacion

Saludos y gracias de antemano

El problema es que, dentro del método obtenerCategoriaParticipante() utilizas el miembro de la clase this->categorias, que no inicializas dentro de dicho método y es el valor de esta variable el que retornas al final del método.
A medida que vas iterando por el resultado de listarParticipantes(), esta variable va acumulando los resultados de todas las llamadas a obtenerCategoriaParticipante().
Es decir, en la primera llamada, digamos que para el participante 1, tendrá solo los resultados de este, pero en la segunda, para el participante 2, va a tener los del participante 1 y después los del participante 2.
En la siguiente, con el 3, los del 1, 2, y 3, y así sucesivamente.
Dado que no explicas por qué has decidido utilizar ese miembro de la clase y no una variable local, es difícil decir cuál es la verdadera solución a tu problema, pero yo diría que tienes básicamente dos alternativas:

La más recomendable, es usar una variable local. Si vas a llamar al método y a iterar por ese resultado, es raro que este deje almacenado, a su vez, el mismo resultado en el miembro de la clase.
Algo en la línea de:
 $resultado = $this->db->query($sql);
 $categorias = [];
 while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
 {
     categorias[] = $row;
 }
 return categorias;


Si debes seguir usando el miembro de la clase, entonces limpiarlo cada vez que se llama al método y antes de agregarle los resultados de la base de datos, de manera que tenga solo estos:
Algo en la línea de:
 $resultado = $this->db->query($sql);
 this->$categorias = [];
 while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
 {
     this->categorias[] = $row;
 }
 return this->categorias;



OJO: He escrito la respuesta aquí mismo, no estoy 100% de la sintaxis de la sentencia de inicialización, pero si comprendes la idea, seguro ya tú encuentras la sintaxis correcta.

Hola @jachguate gracias por la respuesta, soluciono el problema con e "$this->$categorias = [];", le había hecho un unset($this->$categorias), pero se que no era la mejor solución. en este caso no estoy usando una variable local por que la función la estoy llamando desde una clase. GRACIAS
